# How to make laravel Many-To-One (hasMany) relationship works

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I related 2 models - Category and News, each new can have 1 category assign to itself. The problem is that I can't access the category that I assigned to the new, my question is how to make it work ? And why my way doesn't work.

Categroy model-

```
public function news(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\News');
}
```

News model -

```
public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Categroy');
}
```

CategoryController -
`$categories = DB::table('categroys')->get();
 dd($categories->news);`

message -

```
"Property [news] does not exist on this collection instance."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) your `news` method as follow:

```
$categories = Category::with(['news'])->get();
dd($caregories);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. This line will return instance of Collection. It is not a model itself. It is all items in *categories* table. 
   `$categories = DB::table('categroys')->get();`

   ```
   foreach($categories as $category) {
      $news = $category->news();
   }
   ```
2. But in this case you will get a first item and it is a model

   ```
       $categories = DB::table('categroys')->first();
   ```

So you should use either **foreach** or take only the first item of collection.

Comment: "Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::news does not exist."

Answer (score 0):

> This is [Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships). This relationship only works with Model.

```
$categories = Categroy::all();

foreach($categories as $category) {
    // $category->news
}
```